# How to add gitLab repository with Xcode 9?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, gitlab, xcode9

[image: Xcode 8]

[image: Xcode9]

Can anyone tell how to add gitlab repository in Xcode 9 as in new Xcode the option has been removed to Add Repository.

Comment: A Google search for `How to add GitLab repository with XCode 9` yields this? https://www.raywenderlich.com/153084/use-git-source-control-xcode-9

Comment: Already checked this I want for gitLab Account.

Comment: But Gitlab is just a server that serves a normal Git repo, no? Just add it as a repository?

Comment: The second image is of new Xcode 9 in old Xcode 8 I was doing like that only.

Comment: Indeed! They seem to have integrated deeply with Github, but I can't find any mention of standalone Git repos. Wtf?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow this steps https://www.raywenderlich.com/153084/use-git-source-control-xcode-9

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/405/

then on the left-side click source-control icon then add remote (see image)

NOTE: add url from gitlab

[image]